# wcstombs_s is not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using `wcstombs_s` in my code to convert `CString` to `char*`. here is code:

```
  AddItemToListIncludeSubFolder(CString FolderPath, CString Parent)
  {
    char szInputPath[1024]; 

    memset(szInputPath,1024,'\0');
    size_t CharactersConverted=0;

    wcstombs_s(&CharactersConverted, szInputPath, FolderPath.GetLength()+1, 
        FolderPath, _TRUNCATE);
  }
```

It raises exception some time. Memory exception. is `wcstombs_s` is not working when `CString` is too long like 1024 character or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Present a complete small program that exhibits the error, please. As your code is right now you have two `memset` calls, on variables that are not used in your call to `wcstombs_s`. That's just noise, as far as explaining your problem goes.

Comment: BOOL CPDF2ImageDlg::DeleteItemFromListIncludeSubFolder(CString FolderPath, CString Parent)
{
 MSG msg;
 HANDLE hFile;
 WIN32_FIND_DATAA lpFile;
 char FilePath[MAX_PATH_LENTH];
 char szInputPath[MAX_PATH_LENTH]; 
 size_t CharactersConverted=0;

 memset(FilePath,MAX_PATH_LENTH,'\0');
 memset(szInputPath,MAX_PATH_LENTH,'\0');
 
wcstombs_s(&CharactersConverted, szInputPath,FolderPath.GetLength()+1, FolderPath, _TRUNCATE);

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code you can check now. It raise run time exception some time that related to memory.

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter of `wcstombs_s` is the size of the output buffer, *not* the size of the string to be converted.  If `FolderPath` is longer than 1024 characters, you're writing memory out of bounds because `wcstombs_s` thinks it has a bigger buffer than it does.

Try this instead:

```
wcstombs_s(&CharactersConverted, szInputPath, sizeof(szInputPath),
    FolderPath, _TRUNCATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're also using memset incorrectly, you have interchanged the second and third parameters.

Answer (score 0):

should use wcstombs_s(&CharactersConverted, szInputPath, 1023, FolderPath.GetString(), _TRUNCATE); 
the third parameter is the buffer size of szInputPath, even FolderPath's length exceed 1024, this function still not throw exception

Comment: I did the same but problem was still arise.

Answer (score 0):

CString is #defined based on whther the UNICODE define is set.  If it is set CString translates to CStringW otherwise to CStringA.  Thing is its perfectly valid to use these classes directly.  Furthermore they perform conversion between the 2.

So if you write the following code:

```
CStringA ansiAstring( wideString );
char* ansiCStr = ansiString.GetString();
```

Its as simple as that.